# Customise registration page in spree commerce 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to customise this view file: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.0/frontend/app/views/spree/checkout/registration.html.erb

Here's the code:

```
<%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/error_messages', :locals => { :target => @user } %>
<h1><%= Spree.t(:registration) %></h1>
<div id="registration" data-hook>
  <div id="account" class="columns alpha eight">
    <!-- TODO: add partial with registration form -->
  </div>
  <% if Spree::Config[:allow_guest_checkout] %>
    <div id="guest_checkout" data-hook class="columns omega eight">
      <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/error_messages', :locals => { :target => @order } %>
      <h6><%= Spree.t(:guest_user_account) %></h6>
      <%= form_for @order, :url => update_checkout_registration_path, :method => :put, :html => { :id => 'checkout_form_registration' } do |f| %>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :email, Spree.t(:email) %><br />
          <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'title' %>
        </p>
        <p><%= f.submit Spree.t(:continue), :class => 'button primary' %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The login form for existing users ends up (in the browser) in place of this comment:

```
<!-- TODO: add partial with registration form -->
```

That's still the case when you turn javascript off. I'm trying to figure out how it gets there, and how I can customise it.

UPDATE: Just to be clear, I know how to modify views with deface, or override them completely. It's the fact that a form appears in place of the TODO comment that I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use [Deface](https://github.com/spree/deface) to slightly modify that view (make new file with 'same' path (`app/overrides/spree/checkout/registration.rb`) so you will have them organized) or create new view in your `app/views/spree/checkout/` directory named `registration.html.erb`, it should be rendered instead of default one.

Edit: I misunderstood you, to turn off unwanted override you should add another override with path specified above and put into it:

```
Deface::Override.new(
  virtual_path: 'spree/checkout/registration',
  name: "name_of_override", # you have to provide proper name here
  disabled: true)
```

To find out right name you can look into every spree extension for overrides of `registration.rb` or into your logs, all applied overrides should be listed there after visiting that page.

UPDATE BY ORIGINAL POSTER:

It turns out it's an override in the spree_auth_devise gem: https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/master/app/overrides/auth_user_login_form.rb

Comment: I've already over-ridden the view, and know how to change it. It's specifically the registration form magically appearing in place of a comment that I'm having trouble with, as I mention in the final part of my question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you, it's probably added by some other override. It's quite hard to locate them as they may be spread over all spree gems, but it can be done by looking into every spree extension and searching for file located in `overrides/spree`checkout/registration.rb` (or just for `registration.rb`, grepping allowed) and turning off that override (I'll update my answer to show how to do that).

Comment: @zrl3dx : where to put this code? `Deface::Override..` I want to customize [header part](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/shared/_main_nav_bar.html.erb) of spree.

Comment: @GaganGami: you can add all overrides to `app/overrides/spree/path/to/overriden/file` - this way you won't get lost in your overrides.